# How to flip type on a path in InDesign using ExtendScript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I try to create type on a path and then flip type on a path in InDesign using ExtendScript:

```
var myDocument = app.documents.add();
myDocument.documentPreferences.pageWidth = 120;
myDocument.documentPreferences.pageHeight = 120;

var myOval = myDocument.ovals.add();
myOval.absoluteRotationAngle = 180;
myOval.geometricBounds = [2.5, 2.5, 117.5, 117.5];
myOval.strokeWeight = 0;

var myTextPath = myOval.textPaths.add();
myTextPath.flipPathEffect = FlipValues.FLIPPED;
myTextPath.parentStory.appliedFont = "Arial\tRegular";
myTextPath.parentStory.pointSize = 10;
myTextPath.parentStory.leading = 12;
myTextPath.parentStory.justification = Justification.CENTER_ALIGN;
myTextPath.contents = "text in a circle";
```

The type is not displayed in InDesign.

How can I flip type on a path in InDesign using ExtendScript?

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly your desired result should look like. So there can be different solutions. For example you could 'unclose' the oval (make it an open path):

```
var myDocument = app.documents.add();
myDocument.documentPreferences.pageWidth = 120;
myDocument.documentPreferences.pageHeight = 120;

var myOval = myDocument.ovals.add();
myOval.absoluteRotationAngle = 180;
myOval.geometricBounds = [2.5, 2.5, 117.5, 117.5];
myOval.strokeWeight = 0;

// make an extra point on the path
var p = myOval.paths[0].pathPoints[0];
myOval.paths[0].pathPoints.add(p.properties);

// make the path an open path
myOval.paths[0].pathType = PathType.OPEN_PATH;

var myTextPath = myOval.textPaths.add();
myTextPath.flipPathEffect = FlipValues.FLIPPED;
myTextPath.parentStory.appliedFont = "Arial\tRegular";
myTextPath.parentStory.pointSize = 10;
myTextPath.parentStory.leading = 12;
myTextPath.parentStory.justification = Justification.CENTER_ALIGN;
myTextPath.contents = "text in a circle";
```

Output:

[image]